# Albedo using Landsat 8 not giving correct values

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to get albedo for my study area but my values are not coming good. I need values in range of 0-1 but these values are out of this range. I don't know when I multiply scale value, its not working yet. My code is

```
//cloud mask
function maskL8sr(col) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = col.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);
}


var albedo = function(image){
  var alb = image.expression(
  "((0.356*blue)+(0.130*red)+(0.373*nir)+(0.085*swir)+(0.072*swir2)- 0.018)/ 1.016",
  {
    'red': image.select('B3'),
    'blue':  image.select('B1'),
    'nir':  image.select('B4'),
    'swir':  image.select('B5'),
    'swir2':  image.select('B7')
  });
  return(image.addBands(alb.rename("albedo"))).multiply(0.0001);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2020-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(albedo)
                  .map(maskL8sr);

// print("dataset",dataset);

var myAlbedo = dataset.select("albedo").mosaic(); 
// print("myAlbedo",myAlbedo);

Map.addLayer(myAlbedo, Albedo_pallete, "Albedo" )
```

The script is given: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0da82ade43f03592f22233123d40a67a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR#bands) image collection has a scale of `0.0001`, i.e, values are between `0` and `10,000` instead of `0` and `1` as the albedo function expects. Multiply the bands with `0.0001` before doing the calculation.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c50c68a9e55f951fd7f44f75b6a5078c

Note that this image collection is deprecated, so might want to switch to [`LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands). To get these values between `0` and `1` you have to multiply with `2.75e-05` and subtract `0.2`. Band names have also changed and you have to tweak your cloud masking function.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/85db598d7343fcb7588ce0f7c46e8055